Nextjs: Page not found in Netlify after deploying it except the root layout?
After deploying my project to netlify, I faced a strange behavior, only the root layout that contains the header was displayed.
This is my project repo:
https://github.com/Kiritsu0/Facebook-Clone
This is my netlify project link:
https://facebook-clone0.netlify.app/
This is netlify.toml code:
    [[redirects]]
    from = "/Facebook-Clone/_next/image"
    to = "/.netlify/images?url=:url&w=:width&q=:quality"
    status = 200

      [redirects.query]
      url = ":url"
      w = ":width"
      q = ":quality"

    [[redirects]]
    from = "/_ipx/*"
    to = "/.netlify/images?url=:url&w=:width&q=:quality"
    status = 200

      [redirects.query]
      url = ":url"
      w = ":width"
      q = ":quality"

    [context]

      [context.production]

      [context.master]

I tried changing the base directory but nothing works, to be honest I do not have any idea how I can solve this, since I tried to deploy it in github and this problem did not occur.

The cause of the problem was something I have previously done and forgotten about: Modifying the next.config.app file code. Even though it is working now, however, I do not know why it was working for GitHub but not for Netlify.
Anyway this is what should be written in the file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig

(Normally you do not have to make any changes since this is the original code of next.config.js)
